# JavaScript match ( followed by a digit

Tags: javascript, regex

In string `n+n(n+n)`, where `n` stands for any number or digit, I'd like to match `(` and replace it by `*(`, but only if it is followed by a number or digit.

**Examples:**

- I'd like to change `2+22(2+2)` into `2+22*(2+2)`,
- I'd like to change `-1(3)` into `-1*(3)`,
- `4+(5/6)` should stay as it is.

This is what I have:

```
var str = '2+2(2+2)'.replace(/^[0-9]\(/g, '*(');
```

But it doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `^`, and group the digits:

```
'2+2(2+2)'.replace(/([0-9])\(/g, '$1*(')
'2+2(2+2)'.replace(/(\d)\(/g, '$1*(')    //Another option: [0-9] = \d
```

**Suggestion**: `2.` is often a valid number (= `2`). The following RegExp removes a dot between a number and a parenthesis.

```
'2+2(2+2)'.replace(/(\d\).?\(/g, '$1*(') //2.(2+2) = 2*(2+2)
```

Parentheses create a group, which can be referenced using `$n`, where *n* is the index of the group: `$1`.

You started your RegExp with a `^...`, which means: Match a part of the string which starts with `...`. This behaviour was certainly not intended.

Comment: I don't think the the lookahead is necessary - the OP said *"only if it's being followed by number"* but I think they meant "only if it *follows* a number"

Comment: +1 But you should be consistent with the use of `[0-9]` and `\d`

Comment: I've updated my answer, because the question has changed. The look-ahead disappeared.

Comment: **NullUserException**: Fixed, **Rob W**: That works. Thanks! (@Update: This works too, thanks).

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = '2+2(2+2)+3(1+2)+2(-1/2)'.replace(/([0-9])\(/g, '$1*(');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXU4Y/3/

This follows what you wrote (the bracket must follow a number).

So `4(` will be changed to `4*(` it could be important for example for `4(-1/2)`

Comment: Not replied as first, but works fine (but still Rob's W solution is a bit better). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use capturing groups and backreferences to do it.

Check out [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html), under "Replacement Text Syntax" for more details.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/yuRTw/) that does what you ask for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: damnit! 8 minutes too late :(

Comment: @above: But helpful! Nice of you that you gived a fiddle, with same examples like me. Thanks ;).